# How to catch Hibernate SQL EXCEPTIONS IN SPRING

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate

i am using hibernate to execute sql statements in spring but to handle exceptions i used hibernate exception and sql exception but i am not able to handle exceptions

if my sql server is not on or not accessable i am not able to catch exception i am getting error

```
org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException
```

here `name.save(user);`

is hibernate command that executes sql command

how to catch this type of exceptions

i am getting errors

Unreachable catch block for JDBCConnectionException.This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

Unreachable catch block for SQLException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement body

mycode:

```
try
{
      ApplicationContext appContext = 
              new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("/config/BeansInfo.xml");
    TokenBo tokenBo = (TokenBo)appContext.getBean("TokenBo");
    TokenModel token = new TokenModel();
    token.setNumber(Number);
    token.setID(ID);
}

catch(JDBCConnectionException ex  )
{
  System.out.println(ex);
}
catch(SQLException e){}
```

Comment: i also want to catch sql non executable exceptions like clashing primary key how to catch that exceptions

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hibernate exception handling](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7707936/hibernate-exception-handling)

Comment: @Labeo never put additional information into comments; always update your question - don't expect other people to read through the (possibly lengthy) list of comments.

Answer (score 2):

Use **JDBCConnectionException** for connection related exceptions and **ConstraintViolationException** for constrain violation. You should use other exceptions as per your requirement. See [enter link description here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/exception/package-summary.html)

Comment: it is giving   Unreachable catch block for JDBCConnectionException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement 
  body
 - Unreachable catch block for JDBCConnectionException. This exception is never thrown from the try statement 
  body

Comment: Use multiple catch block instead of using OR.

Comment: still i am facing same problem

Comment: would u please provide me sample code coz I am also working over Spring MVC + Hibernate. This worked fine for me.

Comment: can you give some solution

Comment: yeah!! you are using SQLException in second catch which is a parameter used by JDBCConnectionException. So u can't use both.

Comment: Actually as you are using Spring MVC, I am suggesting you to use a GlobalExceptionHandler by AOP to handle exceptions. It would be much better.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to @Tanjim Rahman,

The Code Snippet

In UserDAOImpl.java

Use ConstraintViolationException to catch the duplicate Entry

```
@Override
public String addUser(User user) 
{
    Session openSession = sessionFactory.openSession();
    String retStr = null;

    try
    {
        openSession.getTransaction().begin();
        openSession.persist(user);
        openSession.getTransaction().commit();

        retStr = "success";
    }
    catch (ConstraintViolationException e)
    {
        openSession.getTransaction().rollback();

        String[] tmpArr =  e.getSQLException().toString().split(":");
        String[] anotherTmpArr = null;

        if( tmpArr.length > 1)
        {
            anotherTmpArr = tmpArr[1].split("for key");
        }

        retStr = anotherTmpArr[0];

    }
    catch (HibernateException e) 
    {
        retStr = e.getLocalizedMessage();
    }

    finally 
    {
        openSession.close();
    }


    return retStr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you may only catch exceptions that are thrown at you directly (at least for checked exceptions...). If you really want to handle this specific error situation in any reasonable way, there is the possibility to catch what is thrown at you and inspect the cause of the exception provided

```
try {
    // some hibernate calls
} catch (GenericJdbcException ge) {
    if(ge.getCause() != null && ge.getCause() instanceof SQLException) {
        SQLException se = (SQLException)ge.getCause();
        if(se.getErrorCode() == -911) {
            // your error handling for this case
        }else{
            throw ge; // do not swallow unhandled exceptions
        }
    }else{
        throw ge // do not swallow unhandled exceptions
    }
}
```

Credit [Oracle Community](https://community.oracle.com/thread/1260113)

Comment: i am not able to have GenericJdbcException  it is asking to create a class of it

Comment: try this https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6/html/API_Documentation/files/javadoc/org/hibernate/exception/GenericJDBCException.html